# How do I know the polarity of pins on a DC 2.1mm power connector using the schematic

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, led-strip

So, I'm designing a PCB for a project I've been working on recently. I want to include a 2.1mm DC power jack, to power the components (LED strips in this case) I have found a suitable connector:
Kobiconn 163-179PH-EX
https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Kobiconn/163-179PH-EX?qs=Xb8IjHhkxj5l2UOaIqcGCw==?

Here is a recreation of what I see in EAGLE:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzoYH1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, using this and the other information in the library, I am unable to work out which wire is the live, and which one is the neutral, which I will connect to ground of my Raspberry Pi 3B

Here is a link to the EAGLE library containing the part:

 https://1drv.ms/u/s!Alkpzq1-4_ESg6oWE3KvkgNWk3Dg6w

 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet for that part shows the required PCB layout - you will have to check that layout against the available parts in the Eagle library, or make your own footprint to suit.

If you do any amount of PC layout, you WILL need to make your own schematic components and PCB footprints.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn’t seem to find this information on the data sheet, do you know where else it could be.

Comment: The PCB layout is lower left drawing on the datasheet.  It shows the pin dimentions and location, but not the pad or hole sizes required. The pins are marked with the letters "A", "B", "C".  A drawing just below the PCB layout shows pin A is the center contact, C is the outer, and B is the switched contact.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Normally you'd have the positive lead on A (the inner pin) and the negative on C (the outer barrel).

B is used where switching is required, you can leave it open or connect it to C.

In the past, negative was sometimes used for the center pin, but usually it's positive these days. Check your actual requirements. And check the actual footprint-pin mapping and footprint dimensions the first time you use a new footprint just in case there is an error, **whether you made it yourself or not**.